# Resize HD on VMware

Tags: hard-drive, vmware

I am having trouble resizing my Disk space on VMware, can someone help me please?

[image: partitions in Disks program]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to increase the _disk_ size (say from currently 43 G to 64 G), or do you only want to increase the size of one of the _partitions_ (root partition or "My files")? Depending on the intention there are different ways. And yes, you can increase even mounted partitions in a running system with `resize2fs`.

Comment: I want to merge all drives together into one single partition.

Answer (score 1):

I actually install GParted and it was really easy to redistribute the disk space.

Thanks everyone for your assistance.